# click on a button - bind a click function to another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}

$('#btna').click(function(){
  $('#btnb').onclick = test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Clicking on `btna` I want just bind `test()` function to `btnb` and NOT execute them.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `bind` event?

Comment: May I ask why you just want to bind it and not execute it already? Why not execute already?

Comment: jqueery objects (as returned by `$(selector)` are not DOM elements, so adding onclick like that is doomed to fail ... also you'd want `=test;` not `=test();` - unless calling `test()` returns a function

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There you go!

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}
 
  $('#btna').click(function(){
     $( "#btnb").unbind( "click" ); // just incase user clicks the button A multiple times
     $('#btnb').click(function(){test();})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Comment: `.click(function(){test();})` ... so that's just `.click(test)` ... and "There you go!" hardly explains anything

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, I'm just happy that we've solved puerto's problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for bind event

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}

$('#btna').click(function(){
  $('#btnb').bind({click:test});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}

$('#btna').click(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#btnb', test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#btnb', test);` ... why not `$('#btnb').click(test);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this);
}
$(function() {
  var btnb = $('#btnb');
  $('#btna').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
    if (btnb.data('enbld')) {
      return; /* avoid multiple click bindings */
    }
    btnb.on('click', test).data('enbld', 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not bind it the same way as you did the first click event.

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}

$('#btna').click(function(){
  $('#btnb').click(function() { test(); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Comment: `$('#btnb').click(function() { test(); });` or real programmers use `$('#btnb').click(test);` :p

Comment: Many ways of doing it :)

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this.

```js
function test() {console.log('test');}

$('#btna').click(function(){
  $('#btnb').bind('click', test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btna'>BUTTON A</button>
<button id='btnb'>BUTTON B</button>
```

Comment: "Do it like this" - why?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am saying it is the only way to do it. I said 'Do it like this' because in question he mentioned the word "bind" so I suggested a way which utilizes the binding event.